# Which do ordinary people and scientists use arguments for their belief that other people also have minds?

Tags: philosophy-of-mind, argumentation, consciousness

Which do ordinary people use arguments for their belief that other people also have minds?

Comment: Exclude science (empirical truth), which takes it for granted: experience just confirms their existence. Therefore, ordinary people take it for granted too. The problem is purely philosophical (truths deeper than empirical).

Comment: And what empirical arguments are used?

Comment: "for granted" = no need for argumentation. Try using the scientific method with simple observation: you will find that people exist. Then, you will post questions regarding the validity of simple observation... then, you will start understanding that the problem is not empirical (scientific), but metaphysical (ergo, philosophical).

Comment: Scientists and ordinary people don't need an argument for the existence of other minds. It's a purely philosophical question and even then is more an exercise than a question of import. Vanishingly few well-balanced people take seriously the possibility that there aren't other minds.

Comment: Does the Best Explanation Argument for the existence of other minds count as empirical? Won't ordinary people and scientists use this argument?

Comment: Probably each of the 30 some billion humans who have been born has seen it differently. That's what we're all doing here. *Seeing Moves*

Comment: @Johnny5454 _Best Explanation_ falls into the _exegetics_ or _hermeneutics_ categories, which are not related to experience. The common philosophical definition of empirical is _coming from sense intuition_ (the world can only be experienced by means of the senses). God, being, ontology, the others, etc. are metaphysical subjects.

Comment: I am an ordinary person. Which arguments can I use to justify my belief that other people also have minds?

Answer (score 1):

When I search for "*Best Explanation Argument for the existence of other minds*", from SEP we have this:

> At a superficial glance it can look as if there is agreement about what the problem is and how we might address it. But on closer inspection one finds there is little agreement either about the problem or the solution to it. Indeed, there is little agreement about whether there is a problem here at all.

So. There's no problem, if people don't agree that there is one. Solve that, and your name will stand above Einstein, Lincoln and Newton forever.

Comment: What arguments do ordinary people and scientists use?

Comment: @Johnny5454 I think no one has asked this question in this way before. It is your question. The answer is yours as well. But the doorway is probably in another place. I have my answer, but i cannot convey it to someone else.